# Ubuntu update from 16.04 to 18.04

Tags: 16.04, 18.04

I'm trying to update my Ubuntu from 16.04 to 18.04 but I keep getting an error. I have been struggling with this and have still not found a fix. Any ideas on what to do?

There is no error being displayed so I am at a loss on how to proceed.

Command: `sudo do-release-upgrade`

Terminal output:

```
Checking for a new Ubuntu release
Get:1 Upgrade tool signature [819 B]                                           
Get:2 Upgrade tool [1,246 kB]                                                  
Fetched 1,247 kB in 0s (0 B/s)                                                 
authenticate 'bionic.tar.gz' against 'bionic.tar.gz.gpg' 
extracting 'bionic.tar.gz'

Reading cache

Checking package manager
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree        
Reading state information... Done
Hit http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu xenial InRelease                        
Ign http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease                     
Get:1 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security InRelease [109 kB]     
Hit http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease                       
Ign http://dl.google.com/linux/earth/deb stable InRelease                      
Get:2 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates InRelease [109 kB]    
Hit http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable Release                       
Hit http://dl.google.com/linux/earth/deb stable Release                        
Get:3 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports InRelease [107 kB]  
Fetched 325 kB in 0s (0 B/s)                                                   
Reading package lists... Done    
Building dependency tree          
Reading state information... Done

Restoring original system state

Aborting
Reading package lists... Done    
Building dependency tree          
Reading state information... Done
```

Update:

As suggested in the comments, I have tried the same command from the console. But I still get the same result. I did the following:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
sudo do-release-upgrade
```

Comment: Do you have enough disk space? Memory? Logout, then try from the console only (e.g. Control-Alt-F3)

Comment: I initially did not have enough disk space. Then I cleared some memory and tried again. I have approximately 40 GB empty now, and I think that is more than enough. I’ll try from the console and let you know.

Comment: I cleaned my disk finally! I've tried `sudo apt autoremove` but it just says `0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.` so I guess nothing is happening. Any other ideas?